# Failing to create Firefox Web Driver in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, selenium, tomcat, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have application where I need to use Selenium with Firefox Webdriver.

I'm using below configurations:

> OS : Windows 8
>
> IDE : Eclipse
>
> Selenium 3 and tomcat7.
>
> Mozilla version : 54.0.1
>
> Geckodriver version: 0.18.0

Here is the code snapshot of what I've done so far.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\dalakada1\\Desktop\\dev\\geckodriver.exe");
System.out.println("1");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
System.out.println("2");

capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
System.out.println("3");

try
{
    System.out.println("3.5");
    //create driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.out.println("4");
```

It doesn't go beyond 3.5.
I searched on Google and could not find anything useful.

Do I need to include `geckodriver.exe` in web-inf/res?

Comment: it should be `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);`

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Comment: Browser version and geckodriver version ?

Comment: @Tuks Mozilla version : 54.0.1 Geckodriver version: 0.18.0

Comment: Can you try without desire capability code and let me know like there lines `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\dalakada1\\Desktop\\dev\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");`

Comment: @N Mert Aydin, have u tried this so far ?

Comment: @Tuks yes I just tried and unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Anymore ideas, do you think is it because config ?